# Baltimore to Las Vegas- why does the flight path change from day to day

Tags: air-travel, usa, las-vegas, maryland, baltimore

The flight path consistently changes from day to day, I understand sometimes it is due to weather but occasionally there are no storms and the flight will still be flying in a "funky" pattern. Just curious as to why?

Comment: some more details would help here: where are you seeing the flight path? (It might not always be right.) Maybe some screen shots?

Comment: I suggest migration to [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

In general it's always going to be due to "weather" in one form of another.

The most visual version of this is when there are storms en-route, and the different course is chosen to avoid the storm.

However even when there's no storms, there are still winds - and they can vary dramatically depending on the actual route taken, as well as the altitude the plane in flying at.

Specifically for the US, the "[Jet Stream](http://www.weather.com/maps/activity/aviation/sundayusjetstream_large.html)" generally means winds from west to east, however their exact path and strength varies on a a day-by-day and even hour-by-hour basis, so airlines will frequently vary their route to avoid particularly strong head-winds.

For example, consider [this map of the Jet Stream winds from last Wednesday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpvR0.jpg) - you can see how specific routes across the country would result in lower headwinds (perhaps not from Baltimore in this particular case, but consider for a route such as Atlanta to Las Vegas)

Additionally avoiding particularly bad turbulence can also cause them to pick a specific route, although other than during storms this would normally be done by changing altitude rather than route.